# NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog getting while adding mat dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

Am getting "NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog", below is the code

Open stackblitz link and click on orders link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/tms-prototype

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should import `MatDialog` from the same place where you have imported `MatDialogModule` since they represent different bundles.

So use:

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
                                                                           ^^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
```

because you imported `MatDialogModule` in `SharedModule` from `@angular/material/dialog`

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tms-prototype-zidkcg?file=src/app/shared/shared.module.ts)**

Comment: Downvoter please elaborate what you don't like in my answer?